# dialog box with error message while working with swing in java

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, braces

i'm not a good programmer in java. While I work with this coding I was stuck with some errors. Could anyone pls help me?

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test4 implements ActionListener

{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception

    {

        JFrame f=new JFrame("test 4");

        JButton b=new JButton("gud morning");

        JButton b1=new JButton("yes or no");

        b.addActionListener(this);

        b1.addActionListener(this);

        Container content=f.getContentPane();

        content.add(b,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        content.add(b1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setVisible(true);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.setSize(100,100);

        }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

{

    String s=e.getActionCommand();

    if(s.equals("gud morning"))

    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"gud morning","My Message");

    }

    else if(s.equals("yes or no"))

    {


        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmMessageDialog(f,"yes or no","it is also my message",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION)==0);

        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"u clicked yes button");

        }

        else

        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"u clicked no button");

        }

    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
\ram>javac test4.java test4.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) ^ test4.java:25: error: class, interface, or enum expected if(s.equals("gud morning")) ^ test4.java:28: error: class, interface, or enum expected } ^ 3 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is being teminated by a `;` which will make the `else` branch incorrect. Remove the `;`

```
if(JOptionPane.showConfirmMessageDialog(f,"yes or no","it is also my message",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION)==0);
```

becomes:

```
if(JOptionPane.showConfirmMessageDialog(f,"yes or no","it is also my message",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION)==0)
```

You also have an extra curly brace `}` just before your `actionPerformed` begins.